# How do I create a LinearProgressIndicator in Flutter that replaces an IconButton to show progress to next page?

Tags: flutter

It takes quite a bit of time for the next page to load after an IconButton (that takes you to the next page) is clicked. So, I want the IconButton to be replaced by a LinearProgressIndicator that shows when the next page will be loaded. When the Linear Progress Indicator totally fills up, I want the next page to show up. Below is the IconButton code I currently have, any help will be appreciated!

```
IconButton(
                iconSize: 75.0,
                icon: const Icon(
                  Icons.arrow_right_alt_rounded,
                  color: Colors.blue,
                ),
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const setup6()),
                  );
                }, 
              ),
```

Comment: you could try using a ternary operation like this: 
*loading == false ? IconButton() : LinearProgressIndicator()*

Just don't forget to refresh the state

Comment: Do you exactly know how much time it takes to load? If you dont you can just use LinearProgressIndicator as @HenriqueGuimarães said

Comment: @HenriqueGuimarães I'm new to coding so can you please give specific code? I don't understand what you mean....

Comment: @nsa41620 before you try anything, you should learn how ternary operators work. It's quite simple though. Here's an example: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/ternary-operator-in-dart-programming